# OpenCv Convexity Defect

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.4.6.
I am trying to get all the convexity defect depth_points of the biggest contour. But i am getting the bellow exception

```
Assertion failed (mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)) in unknown function
```

the current code is pasted bellow
Thank you for any help

```
    vector<vector<Point> >hulls( 1 );
    vector<Point> hull;
    std::vector<Vec4i>  defects;
    if(contours.size()>1){
         convexHull( Mat(contours[largest_contour_index]), hulls[0], false );
         convexityDefects(contours[largest_contour_index], hulls[0], defects);
         drawContours(sourceVideo,contours,largest_contour_index,Scalar(255, 0, 0));
         drawContours(sourceVideo,hulls,0,Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        }
```

the error is in this line

```
   convexityDefects(contours[largest_contour_index], hulls[0], defects);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this it works for me:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>     
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

String window_name = "Hand_HSV";
Mat frame,copyFrame;

// Detect Skin from YCrCb
Mat DetectYCrCb(Mat img,Scalar min, Scalar max){
    Mat skin;
    cvtColor(img, skin, cv::COLOR_RGB2YCrCb);
    inRange(skin, min, max, skin);
    Mat rect_12 = getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, Size(12,12) , Point(6,6));
    erode(skin, skin, rect_12,Point(),1);
    Mat rect_6 = getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, Size(6,6) , Point(3,3));
    dilate(skin,skin,rect_6,Point(),2);
    return skin;    
}

void DetectContour(Mat img){
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( img.size(), CV_8UC3 );
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<vector<Point> > bigContours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;


    findContours(img,contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point());

    if(contours.size()>0)
    {
        vector<vector<int> >hull( contours.size() );
        vector<vector<Vec4i>> convDef(contours.size() );
        vector<vector<Point>> hull_points(contours.size());
        vector<vector<Point>> defect_points(contours.size());


        for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
        {
            if(contourArea(contours[i])>5000)
            {
                convexHull( contours[i], hull[i], false );
                convexityDefects( contours[i],hull[i], convDef[i]);

                // start_index, end_index, farthest_pt_index, fixpt_depth

                for(int k=0;k<hull[i].size();k++)
                {           
                    int ind=hull[i][k];
                    hull_points[i].push_back(contours[i][ind]);
                }

                for(int k=0;k<convDef[i].size();k++)
                {           
                    if(convDef[i][k][3]>20*256)
                    {
                        int ind_0=convDef[i][k][0];
                        int ind_1=convDef[i][k][1];
                        int ind_2=convDef[i][k][2];
                        defect_points[i].push_back(contours[i][ind_2]);
                        cv::circle(drawing,contours[i][ind_0],5,Scalar(0,255,0),-1);
                        cv::circle(drawing,contours[i][ind_1],5,Scalar(0,255,0),-1);
                        cv::circle(drawing,contours[i][ind_2],5,Scalar(0,0,255),-1);
                        cv::line(drawing,contours[i][ind_2],contours[i][ind_0],Scalar(0,0,255),1);
                        cv::line(drawing,contours[i][ind_2],contours[i][ind_1],Scalar(0,0,255),1);
                    }
                }

                drawContours( drawing, contours, i, Scalar(0,255,0), 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
                drawContours( drawing, hull_points, i, Scalar(255,0,0), 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
            }
        }
    }
    namedWindow( "Hull demo",cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Hull demo", drawing );

}


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    VideoCapture capture(0);
    //VideoCapture capture("Video_Hand.MPG");
    namedWindow( window_name, cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    if (capture.isOpened()){
        while(true)
        {
            capture >> frame;
            imshow( window_name, frame);

            Mat skinYCrCb = DetectYCrCb(frame,Scalar(0, 100, 80), Scalar(255, 185, 135));
            imshow("Result",skinYCrCb);

            DetectContour(skinYCrCb);

            int c = waitKey(10);
            if( (char)c == 27 ) 
            { 
                break; 
            } 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very useful! Also helps to avoid passing `hull` as a `vector<vector<Point>>` to `convexityDefects`. Good work!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `vector<vector<Point> >hulls` is correct? The documentation (docs.opencv.org) mentions, for the 2nd parameter of `convexityDefects`:

*`convexhull – Convex hull obtained using convexHull() that should contain indices of the contour points that make the hull.`*

So i think it should be rather `vector<vector<int> >hulls`

Comment: <Point> can be used. Everything works fine if i comment 
convexityDefects(contours[largest_contour_index], hulls[0], defects); The error is the data struct used for  defects, I think

Comment: i get the following error "OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN
(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)) in unknown function"